# Python Matplotlib setting axis limits in multi axes environment

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a multi axes plot. I have troubble in setting the ylims of each sub plot. 
I am not providing the data as the problem is related to setting the axes only.

Here is the code:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(x,y1,'-r')
ax2 = plt.subplot(412,sharex=ax1)
plt.plot(x,y2,'-g')
ax3 = plt.subplot(413,sharex=ax1)
plt.plot(x,y3,'-k')
ax4 = plt.subplot(414,sharex=ax1)
plt.plot(x,y4,'-b')
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4)
#make x axis on upper invisible
plt.setp(ax1.get_xaxis(), visible=False)
plt.setp(ax2.get_xaxis(), visible=False)
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax1.set_ylim([20,40])
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.set_ylim([0,0.8])
ax3.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax3.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax4.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.grid(axis="y")
ax2.grid(axis="y")
ax3.grid(axis="y")
ax4.grid(axis="y")
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)
ax4.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, right=0.97, top=0.95, bottom=0.15)        
plt.show()
```

Existing output: We see the ylim of subplot1 has been reset. But, ax2 and ax3 y limits did not change.

Comment: Have you tried also giving set_yticks([0,0.8]) ? By the way I couldn’t see ylim given for ax3 in your code. You can also try using matplotlib and subplots and then plt for each subplot instead of setting an ax foreach subplot. Have you tried?

Comment: I think your code work, notice how `0.5` is not on top of `ax2`, that small distance would account for the space from `0.5` to `0.8`.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's right. I noticed it lately. It is working fine. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

From @QuangHoang in the comments:

> I think your code work, notice how `0.5` is not on top of `ax2`, that small distance would account for the space from `0.5` to `0.8`.